# Bounty ended early?

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty

I had a bounty on [Asymmetric Hessian matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29536/asymmetric-hessian-matrix), started "jun 17 at 9:27", as can be seen for instance from the last modified date on the [asker's page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/5253/nick-kirby).  It is now approximately 18:10 on June 23, and the bounty seems to have already expired.  Shouldn't it go until around 9:27 on June 24?

This is a very minor concern, but <strike>I'm wondering if this is working how it is supposed to</strike> it seems to be a bug.

Added: I had briefly searched before asking, but apparently not very well.  Since posting I found a very similar bug report on meta.stackoverflow.com: [Bounty expired before the expiry time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96130/bounty-expired-before-the-expiry-time)

I also discovered that the bounty start and end shows up in the [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/29536/revisions), so I can confirm that it ended about a day early, at 9:28:36 on June 23.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Did you just start that bounty again yourself or did that happen automatically?

Comment: @Theo: I did it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was my bug, which has been fixed. I've also refunded your 500 rep bounty.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response!

Comment: @Willie hehe, we try to, especially when we get Date math wrong!  I should have posted here before checking in :)